# MySQL, ¿es posible hacer esto en mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy en un Grado superior y estamos dando mysql en workbench y nos han enviado una actividad que no tengo ni idea de cómo hacer... En la teoría pone algo sobre que tablas sin claves no se pueden editar, o algo así, por lo que no estou seguro de que se pueda hacer, pero bueno, pregunto por si acaso.

¡Muchas gracias a cualquiera que ayuda! Ando algo perdido.

El ejercicio pide lo siguiente:

Crea una nueva tabla llamada InformeVentas en la BD Ventas. Dicha tabla estará compuesta por un campo de tipo texto llamado Empleado, otro de tipo numérico llamado CodOficina,  y dos campos de tipo  entero llamados VentasEmpleadosy VentasOficinas. No es necesario definir ninguna clave principal para esta tabla.

Inserta  en  la  nueva  tabla  todos  los  empleados  existentes  en  la  tabla  empleado  con  sus códigos de oficinas correspondientes y con sus VentasOficina y Ventasempleado con un valor de 50000 euros cada una de ellas

Estoy probando a hacer esto:

insert into informeventas (Empleado, Codoficina) select NumEmp, CodOficina from empleado;

update informeventas  set VentasEmpleado = 50000, VentasOficina = 50000 where VentasEmpleado = null;

Pero la segunda función no hace nada, no falla, pero no actualiza.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sentencia está bien construida, pero la manera de especificar que el campo tiene un valor NULL, es incorrecta.

No puedes utilizar operadores de comparación (=, <, >) con el valor null, en su defecto, debes utilizar IS NULL o IS NOT NULL

Prueba a sustituir '=null' por 'is null' a ver que tal.

Comment: Gracias, era eso!